# How do I enable Expert mode in the Craftware slicer?

Tags: heated-bed

I'm using craftware, and I'm trying to figure out how to enable expert mode so that I can adjust the extruder/bed temps. I looked all over the application, the user manual, and googled it, but I cannot find the setting to enable it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, you must click the slice button, then among those options, there is s button to switch to Expert mode. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Welcome to the group! Glad you found a solution. While we were not much help this time, be sure to give us another shot in the future :-)